# How do I display an image in fullscreen mode?

Tags: ios, image, zooming

I'm almost there, just need a little helping hand from a kind soul. I have set up a method to allow a photo to be taken upon single tapping a UIView. That works perfectly. I have also set up a Double Tap gesture which is recognised and works as expected.

However, I am trying to use the double tap to zoom on the photo which is held in the view. I am finding that the zoom happens, but it only expands the photo to the boundary of the UIView which is a box in the middle of the screen.

How do I get the photo to be shown full screen and then to go back again?

```
- (IBAction)didDoubleTapPhoto1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender; {


    NSLog(@"DoubleTap");

    self.photoView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What language/platform are you using?

Comment: I'm building this through storyboard for an iPhone app using Xcode...

Comment: Did manage to get my image view to expand but it is messy - it is behind the original view and doesn't return to the original either.  Any ideas for a simple way to do this?

Comment: So i replaced the aspect fill above with the following and got a response where the picture expands but it now sits on half the screen and also is behind other items on the screen so looks awful. Any easy ways to do this? (IBAction)didDoubleTapPhoto1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender; {
       
        //if (count == 1) {
        NSLog(@"DoubleTap")
        
      
        self.photoView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
       }

Answer (score 0):

My experience of working out what to do here was:

I started trying to expand an image to full screen, but this led to issues with the image
being placed behind other items on the same screen and complication in returning to normal view.

I then created another view controller and created a segue from the original one to this controller. The segue was created by dragging from my tap gesture to the next view controller.

Key steps for me while using information on the board:

In the destination view controller create a property for an IMAGE as well as the ImageView.

In the source view controller be sure to link the image you are passing to the image in the image property just created in the destination view controller within the "prepare for segue".

Going back to the destination view controller, within ViewDidLoad i equated the image set as a property (and which has now been passed the image within the segue), to be the IMAGEVIEW within the source view controller. This is the image view you would have drag and dropped to the view controller.